# How can I print every different word from an input on a different line sorted in an alphabetical order? - Java

Tags: java, string, oop, set, treeset

My goal is to read a text with BufferedReader. I tried something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String line;
        String[] word = new String[1000];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] words = new String[1000];
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
            word = line.split("\\s+");
        }

        Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; ++i) {
            s.add(words[i]);
        }
        for (String value : s)
            System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

For example: 
input:

1. thanks for the help
2. help

output:

1. for
2. help
3. thanks
4. the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not update word after read line in your code.

Try with this:

```
String line;
        String[] word = new String[1000];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
            word = line.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length ; ++i) {
                s.add(word[i]);
            }
        }

        for (String value : s)
            System.out.println(value);
```